# There are 10 trials with a probability of success of .3

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting exactly 3 successes? What is the probability that only the first, second and fourth trials are successes and the rest are failures? Each trial is independent.

I got P(3) = .266827923 using Bernoulli for the first question. I'm not sure how to answer the second question. I was thinking 1-P(1)+P(2)+P(4) is this correct?

Comment: The first question is a direct Binomial question. The second is a particular ordering of the first question.

Comment: Is the probability of success $.03$ as in your title, or $0.3$ as hinted by the value in your answer?

Comment: No.  Judging by your explanation of $P(3)$, $P(1)+P(2)+P(4)$ is the probability of getting exactly $1,2,$  or $4$ successes.

Comment: @Henry sorry it's 0.3, I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting exactly three is just an application of the binomial distribution, where $X$ is the number of sccesses:

$$P(X=3)= \binom{10}{3}(0.3)^{3}(0.7)^7$$

For the specific sequence the chance is just $(0.3)^{3}(0.7)^7$. (really $0.3 \times 0.3 \times 0.7 \times 0.3 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7$, but I gathered the equal terms.

The extra $\binom{10}{3}$ in the total answer is because the successes must occur at three positions out of the total ten and we have that many such runs, instead of just the one specific one.